# Building Xamarin.IOS Visual studio solution from command line

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2012, command-line, msbuild, xamarin.ios

I am trying to build a `Xamarin.iOS` solution in `Visual Studio 2012` from command line. I need as a result application `IPA` file (AdHoc build).

From `IDE` it is no problem - everything is right.
From command line a executing:

```
msbuild "Y:\CloudWorkgroupMobile\CloudWorkgroup.Touch.sln" /p:Configuration=Adhoc;Platform=iPhone;ServerAddress=192.168.160.24 /t:Clean;Build;
```

The above only build solution on `Windows` machine.
Also tried following:

```
msbuild "Y:\CloudWorkgroupMobile\CloudWorkgroup.Touch.sln" /target:_RemoteBuild /p:ServerAddress=192.168.160.24
```

but Bulid was FAILED with:

```
"Y:\CloudWorkgroupMobile\CloudWorkgroup.Touch.sln" (_RemoteBuild target) (1) -> Y:\CloudWorkgroupMobile\CloudWorkgroup.Touch.sln.metaproj : error MSB4057: The target "_RemoteBuild" does not exist in the project. [Y:\CloudWorkgroupMobile\CloudWorkgroup.Touch.sln]
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

the _RemoteBuild target is only available on the Xamarin.iOS project, not on the solution.

change it to:

```
msbuild "Y:\CloudWorkgroupMobile\iosProjectLocation\iosProject.proj" /target:_RemoteBuild /p:ServerAddress=192.168.160.24
```

You should then be good to go.